# Division of polynomials. For which $m$ one polynomial can be divided to other.

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory

Let $p(x) = (x + 1)^m - x^m - 1$ and $q(x) = (x^2+x+1)^2$.
Coefficients if these polynomials are in $\mathbb{R}$

So, the question is: "For which $m$ p(x) can be divided by $q(x)$ without remainder?".

I tried to use this idea: let's simulate GCD's algorithm for $p(x)$ and $q(x)$ and see for which $m$ their gcd is dividable to $q(x)$, but didn't got any intresting results.

So, maybe exists a better solution. I'll be very grateful.

Comment: Do you know complex numbers?

Comment: Yes, of course.

Comment: Show that $q$ divides $p$ iff $p(j)=p'(j)=0$.

Comment: Are you saying that $p$ is divisible by $q$ if $p$ has a multiple root $j$?
Can you explain why is that so?

Comment: @Mindlack Your hint makes no sense at all...

Comment: Sorry, I didn’t remember that $j$ *wasn’t* a standard notation for “the” primitive third root of unity (with positive imaginary part). You can check that a polynomial with real coefficients $r$ is divisible by $x^2+x+1$ iff $r(j)=0$, because $j^2+j+1=0$ and $x^2+x+1$ is irreducible. Moreover, as $x^2+x+1$ is irreducible, $q$ divides $p$ iff $x^2+x+1$ divides $p$ and $p’$, so iff $p(j)=p’(j)=0$. What doesn’t make sense about this?

Comment: Same method(s) in the linked dupe work, using $\, P-\frac{1}{m}(x\!+\!1)P' = x^{\large m-1}-1\ \ $

Comment: @Mindlack The fact that it was given without any context, and so there was no indication that you meant for $j$ to be a primitive third root of unity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint**:

As the roots of $q(x)$ are the complex cubic  roots of unity $\;\omega=\mathrm e^{\tfrac{2i\pi}3}$ and $\omega^2=\bar\omega=\mathrm e^{\tfrac{4i\pi}3}$, and $p(x)$ has to be divisible by the square of $q(x)$, you have to check that $\omega$ and $\omega^2$ are *double* roots of $p(x)$, i.e. that they're roots of $p(x)$ and $p'(x)$.

*Some more details*:

As $p'(x)=m(x+1)^{m-1}-mx^{m-1}$, we have the conditions

- $(\omega+1)^m-\omega^m-1=(-\omega^2)^m-\omega^m-1=0$,
- $(-\omega^2)^{m-1}-\omega^{m-1}=0$.

Comment: Didn't get how we can check that they're roots of $p(x)$. And where is dependence from $m$ in your solution. 
I would be very grateful if you could write a more detailed solution to this problem.

Comment: @Someone $\omega = -\frac12+\frac{i\sqrt3}2$ so $\omega+1=\frac12+\frac{i\sqrt3}2$ which you can also express in polar form.

Comment: @Someone: if they're roots of $q(x)$ and $q(x)$ divides $p(x)$, they're automatically roots of $p(x)$. Note I didn't post a full solution, only a hint.